# Tagged as unclear but perfectly clear to me

Tags: support, specific-question, unclear

I don't get it.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46897692/4843530) was tagged as unclear, but it is perfectly clear to me.  OP says here is code that gives me an error: ... but this code does not give me an error: ... why?  OP even properly tagged and formatted his code.

To be perfectly upfront, when he first wrote the question, the "why" was at the very start of his post, and his post was just one very long sentence, broken only by his properly formatted code samples.  In other languages, long sentences like this are preferred (my own native language included), so ESL speakers are quite comfortable with such sentences.  But I went ahead and edited to make it a little more clear.  My only edit was to move the "why" to the end and make it a separate sentence.

The question was so clear to me that I even did a fiddle to illustrate the problem, and the fiddle contains **only** the information provided by OP.

I even asked for moderator attention after it had been closed as unclear, to no avail.  What am I missing here?

Comment: @StephenLeppik - I was very unsure about the tags.  I am not very active on Meta.  Thanks for helping me out with them.

Comment: Users that have the "pwl" consonant cluster in their user name tend to understand stuff that nobody else does.  So editing is important, but your edit replacing "why is" with "in" doesn't cut it.  You'll no doubt get more mileage out of fixing "i have error".  Nobody knows what that means, except you.

Answer (score 4):

In the initial state, it was total unclear what op was asking. The given question was: "Is the second code sample correct?" which was impossible to answer since there was no intended behavior specified. In addition, the two code samples do not produce the same result. In the first sample a dictionary is generated, in the second one a IEnumberable.

After you edited the question, it became clearer, but there are still other problems with the question.

- The exact error message is missing ("unreadDialogs.key has another (TLAbsPeer) type" isn't what Visual Studio states, neither does the fiddle state that error).
- The question should either have been tagged with [telegram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/telegram) (or at least state that it's about classes from this API) or has to state that TLPeerChannel is derived from TLAbsPeer.

Note, that the stated close reason doesn't mean that all voters have choosen the same close reason. After your edit I would have taken "off-topic > Missing specific problem or error" because of the reasons stated above.

About your edit: If I would have gotten this edit in the review queue, I would have rejected it. You were just guessing that what you interpreted was the actual question that has been asked. It was luck that you got the right question (or at least op was happy with the answer). Adding the fiddle was a good idea although that happened after the question was already closed.

Comment: The original question was "Why this code gives error [CODE] but this 'is all ok'? [CODE]".  The question was not "is this second code all ok.  His sentence was just long and so it is hard for you to see that the why went with 'is all ok'.  He was asking why is the second code ok but the first fails with error. A minor benefit of the doubt to OP yields better understanding.

Comment: It was not luck.  There was no guessing.  The minute I read the question, I knew exactly what he was asking.  It befuddles me that other people can't see it, but obviously quite a number cannot.  But it also befuddles and irritates me that, having seen it, I seem incapable of helping others see the clarity of it.

Answer (score -7):

such tag "uncertain" , "unclear" is subjective. Tag is used to sort question in objective manner.

Comment: Uhmmm.... nope.